# Добавить лидирующие пробелы для чисел

Tags: sql, oracle

Как в Oracle SQL добавить лидирующие пробелы для чисел?
Можете поделится литературой по Oracle SQL? Язык русский/английский.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [LPAD()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/LPAD.html#GUID-0C27B59A-A6CF-43D3-BF4B-07A3D0F2CE20):

```
select lpad(to_char(numeric_column_name), 8, ' ') from ...
```

`8` в данном примере - длина целевой строки.

PS убежден, что лучшая документация по Oracle - это [Oracle Online Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Еще как вариант:

```
select To_Char(100, '999999999') from Dual
```

Строка будет длиной равной количеству девяток плюс позиция под знак (либо пробел либо "-"). Т.е. в целом для примера длина строки будет 10 символов.

Источник:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions181.htm